# Issue with master slave kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have configured master slave kubernetes on ubuntu 16 in AWS server, on post configuration of master, dns and dashboard pods are not running.

Please help to solve this issue.

Below the article, I have followed till dashboard creation

https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-56ccd8fbd4-s9gz7   0/1     Pending   0          3m51s   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-7nr8v                   0/1     Pending   0          7m27s   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-k69n9                   0/1     Pending   0          7m27s   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kmaster                               1/1     Running   0          6m40s   172.31.41.180   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          6m38s   172.31.41.180   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          6m31s   172.31.41.180   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-rtw76                           1/1     Running   0          7m27s   172.31.41.180   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          6m46s   172.31.41.180   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-x2b8x      0/1     Pending   0          66s     <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
ubuntu@kmaster:~$
```

Comment: Some of the kube-system pod are running, this seems like a lack of nodes resources, could you post the result of a `kubectl get nodes` command and `kubectl top nodes`

Comment: smth definitely with Calico CNI and worker node I would say. Need more details  and logs to help you here

Answer (score 0):

Oh no, dude. I just read the article... My advice is to throw it away and use [official kubeadm documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

Each time you will follow your article you will have the same result using old calico yaml(`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml`): coredns pods and all deployment pods will be in `Pending` state

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-56ccd8fbd4-t9mhs   0/1     Pending   0          11m   <none>         <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-kbqnz                   0/1     Pending   0          13m   <none>         <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-rr8r9                   0/1     Pending   0          13m   <none>         <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kmaster                               1/1     Running   0          12m   172.31.6.171   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          12m   172.31.6.171   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          12m   172.31.6.171   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-5nnhl                           1/1     Running   0          13m   172.31.6.171   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          12m   172.31.6.171   kmaster   <none>           <none>
```

Resolution  - use up-to-date CNI yaml from [Installing a pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)

Use `kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml`

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml
configmap/calico-config created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/felixconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ipamblocks.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/blockaffinities.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ipamhandles.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ipamconfigs.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/bgppeers.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/bgpconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/ippools.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/hostendpoints.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/globalnetworkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/globalnetworksets.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/networkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/networksets.crd.projectcalico.org created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-kube-controllers created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/calico-node created
daemonset.apps/calico-node created
serviceaccount/calico-node created
deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers created
serviceaccount/calico-kube-controllers created
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-65b8787765-fgw78   1/1     Running   0          44s   192.168.189.3   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-g27v9                          1/1     Running   0          44s   172.31.6.171    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-8l7ts                   1/1     Running   0          59s   192.168.189.2   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-v42wg                   1/1     Running   0          59s   192.168.189.1   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          8s    172.31.6.171    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-xf4pt                           1/1     Running   0          59s   172.31.6.171    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          18s   172.31.6.171    kmaster   <none>           <none>
```

And please.. Do it in proper way no matter what is written in that article:

1) First you prepare nodes

2) Then you do `kubeadm init` with proper `--pod-network-cidr=` (see next step to understand what exactly pool you need. Its written in CNI page)

3) After that you [installing CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)

3a)Pay attention that from version to version - you should sometimes

4) Next step in to [Join WORKER NODE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#join-nodes)

5)And only then deploy whatever you want

So, back to out process..

After you applied cni and verified all pods are up and running - you [Join WORKER NODE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#join-nodes) and wail till node status become `Ready`

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME      STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kmaster   Ready    master   10m   v1.15.3   172.31.6.171    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-1087-aws   docker://18.9.7
knode     Ready    <none>   27s   v1.15.3   172.31.10.229   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-1087-aws   docker://18.9.7
```

And only after all that stuff feel free to install dashboard :).  Your dashboard yaml wasnt found in my case  -

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
error: unable to read URL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml", server reported 404 Not Found, status code=404
```

So I found it in [new place](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation)

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/alternative/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
```

And here is you dashboard:

```
kubectl get pods  --all-namespaces | grep dashboard
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-6f8d67df77-mc6xf      1/1     Running   0          3m16s
```

Last notice:  As per my experience - there is much easier, comfortable and stable to use Flannel and not Calico. It has less bugs and people less often have issue with it.

Short example for Flannel from scratch:

Master:

```
root@kmaster:~# kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
ubuntu@kmaster:~$   mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
ubuntu@kmaster:~$   sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
ubuntu@kmaster:~$   sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/62e44c867a2846fefb68bd5f178daf4da3095ccb/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Slave:

```
kubeadm join *.*.*.*:6443 --token *****.********** \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:*********************************************************
```

Check:

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-9wzwc          1/1     Running   0          2m55s
kube-system   pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-kblfd          1/1     Running   0          2m55s
kube-system   pod/etcd-kmaster                      1/1     Running   0          2m12s
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          2m10s
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-kmaster   1/1     Running   0          2m
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4gpwt       1/1     Running   0          37s
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-tchdm       1/1     Running   0          93s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-dp6kq                  1/1     Running   0          37s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-gbw8t                  1/1     Running   0          2m55s
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          2m12s


NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  3m13s
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   3m12s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                     AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64     93s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm       93s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64     93s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=ppc64le   93s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=s390x     93s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux       3m11s

NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns   2/2     2            2           3m12s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-5c98db65d4   2         2         2       2m55s
```

Deploy [Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation)

```
ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/alternative/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created


ubuntu@kmaster:~$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-9wzwc                1/1     Running   0          4m13s
kube-system   pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-kblfd                1/1     Running   0          4m13s
kube-system   pod/etcd-kmaster                            1/1     Running   0          3m30s
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-kmaster                  1/1     Running   0          3m28s
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-kmaster         1/1     Running   0          3m18s
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4gpwt             1/1     Running   0          115s
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-tchdm             1/1     Running   0          2m51s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-dp6kq                        1/1     Running   0          115s
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-gbw8t                        1/1     Running   0          4m13s
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-kmaster                  1/1     Running   0          3m30s
kube-system   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-6f8d67df77-m7w59   1/1     Running   0          20s


NAMESPACE     NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  4m31s
kube-system   service/kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   4m30s
kube-system   service/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.109.132.142   <none>        80/TCP                   20s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                     AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64     2m51s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm       2m51s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64     2m51s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=ppc64le   2m51s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=s390x     2m51s
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                2         2         2       2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux       4m29s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                2/2     2            2           4m30s
kube-system   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard   1/1     1            1           20s

NAMESPACE     NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-5c98db65d4                2         2         2       4m13s
kube-system   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-6f8d67df77   1         1         1       20s
```

EDIT1:
Forgot to add - below is how you reset cluser

```
sudo kubeadm reset
rm -rf .kube/
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/etcd /
```

The end.